# Stop mysql from xampp 5.6 will cause a stop for xampp 7.0 xampp mysql server

Tags: php, xampp, controlpanel

I install `xampp 7.0` for `php` development on window machine, that is running on default ports used `80, 443, 3306`. After that I install `xampp 5.6` on same machine.
And configured different ports for it that are `7777, 444, 3307` according to [Setup Two php](http://webdevzoom.com/install-run-multiple-xampp-windows/). All are working fine. Now I open both xampp control panel and start apache and mysql server of both still working fine. But problem is when I first click stop xamp 5.6 mysql server running on 3307 it will stop xampp 7.0 mysql server automatic then in second click stops xampo 5.6 server.

Please provide solution. I make all the things that describe in above link. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you really need to run both at the same time on the same machine?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are using the right XAMP controller to start and stop things

Comment: Thanks for appreciation. Yes I am using correct xammp controller. Yes its also true that too rare chance to run different versions simalteniously.